# Pause Auto-scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which I want to scroll up and down on page load and pause scrolling once the user hovers over the div. I have managed to get the div to scroll up and down however I cannot get it to pause.

Any Suggestions?

```
 <div id="box" class="timeline container" style="overflow:scroll; width:100%; height:300px;">
    //CONTENT
 </div>         

 <script>

    $("#box").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#box').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
    },4000);
    setInterval(function(){

    $("#box").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#box').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
    },4000);

    },8000);


 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you don't use animate for the scroll feature. Instead just increment the scroll position every 100ms (or whatever).

You also need to add flags to determine scroll direction and pause state:

```
// global level variables.
var isPaused = false;
var direction = 1;
var element = $('#box');

// interval for scroll.
setInterval(function () {
    if(!isPaused){
        var pos = element.scrollTop();
        var offset = 1 * direction;
        element.scrollTop(pos + offset);

        // Change the scroll direction when hit an end.
        if ((element[0].scrollHeight - element.scrollTop() == element.outerHeight()) || (element.scrollTop() <= 0)) {
            direction *= -1;
        }
    }

}, 100);
```

Then you can change the `isPaused` flag when on mouseenter and mouseexit events, or use JQuery `hover` event:

```
$('#box').hover(
  function() {
    isPaused = true;
  }, function() {
    isPaused = false;
  }
);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e8oxc71r/2/)

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this but the div does not seem to scroll at all.

Comment: @Mehul: I have just added a jsfiddle that shows it working

Comment: Hi, This worked thanks! How would I get it to scroll back up aswell, and possibly hide the scroll bar?

Comment: Just checked again, it doesn't seem to work when I plug it into my html script.

Comment: @Mehul: Well then perhaps you should put your real code in your question, and `overflow:hidden;` will hide the scroll bars

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop/pause your animation with the jQuery function `stop()` : https://api.jquery.com/stop/